# notepad ++ open full path from clipboard with shortcut

Tags: notepad++, filepath, shortcut

Is there any way to open a file in notepad++ which (its full path) is already available in clipboard?

I would like to do this with a shortcut, but it seems to me, there is no notepad ++ command to do this.
I have already checked this site:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Clipboard_Uses#Using_the_clipboard_text_as_a_parameter

I know the way to set shortcuts and I have already found this command:
right click to a text than "Open File" (Edit - On Selection - Open File)- it works for full path - and I could set a shortcut as well, but I don't want to open a new tab and paste the content of my clipboard to use it every time..

The classic ctrl + O - File -Open... dont work for me, because in the dialog page - I didn't find any way to paste a full path - but I am opened to do this somehow..

So please give me a way, to open files in notepad++ from clipboard full path, if it is exist! :)

Comment: I can paste clipboard content in the `File name:` part of the Ctrl-O Open File dialog. If the pasted text is a full file path (including its directory, its filename and fileextension), pressing Enter or clicking `Open` opens the file.

Comment: you are right! somehow, it didn't work for me, but now, it works properly! :)
It is 3 step instead of 1 hotkey ( I should write a scrpit..): 
ctrl + O
ctrl + V
Enter

But it is enough for me now. : )

Answer (score 0):

To use it even when notepad++ is not in focus, you could press WIN+R and then CTRL+V. Then the file from the clipboard is opened by the default editor for this extension.

Comment: The question asks specifically about opening a file with Notepad++, not with the default application.